# Amazon CloudFront Alternate Domain Names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm totally new to Amazon and all of its services. I have set up Amazon S3 and created a CloudFront distribution but what I want is to give a custom domain name to this CloudFront distribution.

I have created a sub-domain on my server and changed the `CNAME` to the CloudFront distribution link but I can not access to my content on S3. Can anyone tell me full go through how I can set up with alternate domain names?

Comment: *"but i can not access to my content on s3."* Please be more specific.  Do you get an error?  What does the error say?  If you access the files in bucket directly, does that work? i.e., `http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile`

Comment: *"like its have a option of alternate domain names*" It is not clear from your question, but did you configure this new subdomain as an alternate domain name in the cloudfront distribution?

Comment: sorry if my question was not clear. i found the solution. you only have to create a CNAME record in your DNS and put that cname into the AWS cloudfront Alternate domain name and that's it. it's work great.

Answer (score 17):

To give a custom domain name to an Amazon CloudFront distribution:

- Provide an **Alternate Domain Name** when creating your CloudFront distribution
- Create a `CNAME` record in Route 53 (or your own DNS provider) that points to the URL of your CloudFront distribution (eg `d3i29vunzqzxrt.cloudfront.net`), or create an `A` record in Route 53 that uses `Alias = Yes` and select the CloudFront distribution.

From the help tip in the CloudFront console:

> If you want to use your own domain name (for example, www.example.com) instead of the CloudFront domain name (for example, d1234.cloudfront.net) for the URLs for your files, specify up to 100 CNAMEs. Separate CNAMEs with commas or put each on a new line. You also need to create a CNAME record with your DNS service to route queries for www.example.com to d1234.cloudfront.net.

Comment: what do you think about changing *"Create a CNAME record in Route 53..."* to *"Create a CNAME record or `A`-record Alias in Route 53..."* since either is correct?

Comment: Is it possible to deny access to d1234.cloudfront.net after I configured alternate domain names?

Comment: @IvanNikitin Please create a new Question rather than asking a question as a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** 
Since [this release](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudfront-enhances-the-security-for-adding-alternate-domain-names-to-a-distribution/) (Apr 8, 2019) when you add an alternate domain name to a distribution, you must also attach a SSL/TLS certificate to that distribution that covers the alternate domain name.

So, first of all make sure that after you registered the domain name with your domain provider (GoDadday, CloudFlare, Route 53 etc') and created a `CNAME` record
you should do the following:

Add an SSL/TLS certificate from an authorized certificate authority (for example - [Let's Encrypt](https://medium.com/@cubxi/add-wildcard-lets-encrypt-certifications-with-namecheap-6a466df0886f)) to CloudFront that covers the domain name you plan to use with the distribution - to validate that you are authorized to use the domain. (Read more in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)).

And only then update your distribution to add an alternate domain name: 
Open Amazon CloudFront console -> General view -> Edit -> Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) -> enter the CNAME that you want to associate with the CloudFront distribution (for example www or home).

Answer (score 12):

I think the guide is designed to have you spend more than you should. Instead, you should:

1. Add Alternate Domain Name as the guide says.
2. Create "A" record in Route 53, not CNAME. AWS will charge you for each CNAME request.

Comment: Here, under
Configuring Amazon Route 53 to Route Traffic to a CloudFront Web Distribution

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html