# Cloudfront CNAME or DNS CNAME?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'd like my `abc.cloudfront.net` URLs to instead become `static.example.com` type domain names for my static assets.

In the Cloudfront set up screen, there's a confusing "CNAME" option. Should I skip this entirely, and instead use the DNS setup to provide this CNAME mapping instead? I've tried each CNAME specification separately -- either the one in CLoudfront, or the one in DNS mapping -- and then also tried them both together leaving the CNAME option inside the Cloudfront setup while also having the mapping in DNS.

None of this works. When I replace my `abc.cloudfront.net` URLs with my own subdomain now, it gives me a "**500 internal server error**". Not sure what this error is, and where to track it from?

Additional Explanation: 
AWS implementation of CNAME-ing a cloudfront distribution is confusing as heck. Instead of a CNAME, we're supposed to do a A record with an "alias". Anyway neither of these two setups work -- neither the CNAME in Route53, nor the A with alias in Route53.

Comment: Looks like this question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549785/amazon-cloudfront-alternate-domain-names

Comment: Thank you. Except that doesn't work. Which is why the question. The cloudfront.net URL works. The static.example.com with the same URL path as the cf.net url does not work. Just FYI -- I get a "500 internal server error". Not sure where to debug this error. Meanwhile a `dig static.example.com` does not point to Amazon's IPs, it points to my main server IP.

Comment: Part of the answer of the other question is to change your DNS settings *with whoever your DNS provider is* so that the CloudFront addresses are returned, the other part is configuring the alternate domain name in CloudFront.  Both are required. If you've made the change and are not getting the correct DNS response, then I would suggest you are not asking a question corresonding to the actual problem you're having.

Comment: Hi Michael. I setup Cloudfront and put the same CNAME there. Then I headed over to my DNS and created a "CNAME" there--this happens to be Route53 for me, and as many discussions online will reveal, a CNAME is actually not what works, apparently we need to do an "A" record with an "alias". So I did this. As such, both the items are done. Still, I get a 500 internal error.

Comment: There was an error in my DNS setup. Fixed.